# C# I need a more efficient way to check values in multiple checkboxes to change a bool

Tags: c#, checkbox, boolean

So I have this little task where I am trying to change a single bool if any of my checkboxes are turned on.

So I have a boolean

```
Boolean YourAllowedToWork = false;
```

And a set of checkboxes

```
private void 001_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (001.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }

    private void 002_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (002.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }

    private void 003_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (003.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }

    private void 004_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (004.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }

    private void 005_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (005.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }

    private void 006_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (006.Checked)
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            YourAllowedToWork = false;
        }
    }
```

and although I haven't tested it, this looks to me like it will cause issues with conflicting itself and is clearly not very efficient. I'm still pretty new to programming and only 6 days in to C#.

Could anyone show me a better way to accomplish the above? I would assume there is some way of putting all these checkboxes into a list and listening for a change on any of them then checking the list to see if any of the checkbox values are true, if they are true, change the single boolean to true!

Thank you

Comment: How does this even compile? Variable names in c# are not allowed to start with numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store those checboxes on a `generic list` or even in an `array`

*I think the easiest way is using an array*

```
bool YourAllowedToWork = false;
public void Check()
{
   CheckBox[] checkboxes = { chck1, chck2, chck3 };
   foreach(CheckBox checkbox in checkboxes){
      if(checkbox.Checked == true){
          YourAllowedToWork = true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Linq, `bool YourAllowedToWork  = checkboxes.Any(x => x.Checked);`

Comment: Thanks @AndreiSolero
This almost works, but as soon as I add an Else to the if statement it always fires false.

How to I get it to re check the list if I turn the checkboxes back off?

bool YourAllowedToWork = false;
public void Check()
{
   CheckBox[] checkboxes = { chck1, chck2, chck3 };
   foreach(CheckBox checkbox in checkboxes){
      if(checkbox.Checked == true){
          YourAllowedToWork = true;
      }
else
{
YourAllowedToWork = false; //////////////  Issue Here   ///////////////
}
   }
}

Comment: @Oogle_doogleson, you shouln't add an else statement anymore on the `if` block if you only gonna set the `YourAllowedToWork` to false since it is already initialized to `false` on variable declaration

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one event for all checkboxes. In that single event check the checkbox checked state using OR condition.

I think you are using windows application. In your designer file change click event of all check boxes to one event like below

```
this.001.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_Click);
this.002.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_Click);
this.003.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_Click);
```

In code behind file in the click event use or condition for all check boxes

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {           
     YourAllowedToWork = 001.Checked || 002.Checked || 003.Checked;           
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like AndreiSolero's answer but windows forms already stored them in a collection for you by virtue of how it works; controls live in a hierarchy so to appear on a form they must already be stored in a collection that you can query

```
bool youreAllowedToWork = x.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => RegEx.IsMatch("^\\d{3}$", cb.Name).Any(cb => cb.Checked)
```

`x` is the Control (E.g. the form itself or a panel / groupbox) that the checkboxes are inside - you should change this to e.g. `this` if the checkboxes are on the form, or the panel name if they're in a panel .

I've assumed the checkboxes are all inside the form and are also mixed in with other checkboxes that are not interesting for work reason calc, so there is a regex in there to check the name of the Control is 3 digits (though I think you must have obscured the real names in the question code because it should t even compile - c# prohibits names that start with numbers) which restricts the checking to only the work reason checkboxes we are interested in. This regex will likely need changing to account for what your control names really are - Read on for more advice on this point because I'd recommend you make your life easier by not using regex:

If you want to put all the checkboxes in their own panel and have no other non-work-reasons checkboxes in that panel then you can remove the `.Where(...)` and have E.g.:

```
bool youreAllowedToWork = workReasonsPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(cb => cb.Checked)
```

If you have the checkboxes mixed in with other checkboxes that aren't part of the "you're allowed to work" reasons, perhaps simplifying your life by naming them something better than just numbers would help.
Call them all e.g `workReason1`, `workReason2`...

Then the code can be:

```
bool youreAllowedToWork = x.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.Name.StartsWith("workReason")).Any(cb => cb.Checked)
```

---

I would use either the panel approach or the simple-name-with-consistent-prefix approach, because it means that all you have to do to add more work reasons is add another checkbox to the panel/add another checkbox with the same consistency of name

Use the panel approach if your checkboxes are all in the same place in the UI, use the name approach if they're scattered through the UI and mixed in with other non work reason checkboxes